# Why does GSON convert array of objects to array of Strings instead?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jakarta-ee, gson

I'm trying to display a list of objects in a JSP.
The list is a conversion from Java array to Javascript array thanks to GSON.
The algorithm is:

1. Load array list of objects in servlet
2. Convert to a JSON object with GSON
3. forward JSON object to JSP
4. Load JSON object in a Javascript array
5. Display Javascript array as HTML

[image]

The problem is when I loop the JS array it doesn't recognize the elements of the JS array as objects:

[image]

The problem is when I loop the JS array and print its elements, I get the characters of the 1st image! **This means that GSON does not convert the Array as objects but as an Array of Strings**.

**How can I make sure that GSON actually converts the JAVA Array of Objects to a JS Array of Objects?**

My class "Activite":

```
public class Activite {
   private int id;
   private String description;
}
```

Servlet Side:

```
ArrayList<Activite> listActivite = new ArrayList<Activite>();
// ... Fill array from database ...
String jsonActivite = new Gson().toJson(listActivite);
request.setAttribute( "listActivite", listActivite );
requestDispatcher.include(request, response);
```

JSP Side:

```
<!-- Load Array List -->
<script> 
var listActivite =  <%= new Gson().fromJson((String)request.getAttribute("jsonActivite"))%>;
</script>

<p id="demo"><p>

<!-- Print the Array List's objects in the paragraph <p> -->
<script>
var p = document.getElementById("demo");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+=listActivite+"</br></br>";
for(i=0; i<listActivite.length; i++){
    p.innerHTML += 'ID:'+listActivite[i].id+' DESC:'+listActivite[i].description+'</br>';
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Looks to me as if you're converting to JSON **twice** - once in your Java code, and then *again* in your JSP.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you, yes that's an error. I corrected it to fromJson(). But now the JSP won't recognize the fromJson() method. Why?

Comment: Where? There's no `fromJson()` in the code you posted.  It should not be necessary; your JSON string is valid JavaScript so no further parsing is necessary.

Comment: @Pointy I edited the `toJson()` to `fromJson()`  in the code. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy, I should just get the attribute as you said without further parsing. 

`var listActivite =  <%= request.getAttribute("jsonActivite")%>;`

Comment: It doesn't work because you're feeding it an already-parsed JavaScript object literal!  You don't need to parse it - just drop the request attribute (the JSON string) **directly into the JavaScript code**. *edit* yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer as the user Pointy in the question's comments said, is to not parse the request attribute in the JSP.

```
var listActivite =  <%= request.getAttribute("jsonActivite")%>;
```

listActivite is now a plain JS array of objects.

Thank you Pointy.